# Angularjs ng-click doesn't update view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
myApp.controller( 'ModalNewInstanceCtrl', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance', function( $scope, $modalInstance ) {

$scope.tabSelected = 0;

$scope.saveFactor = function () {
    console.log('here');
    $scope.tabSelected = 0;
    console.log($scope.tabSelected);
};
```

That's my controller.

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <div ng-click="tabSelected = 0">Tab 1</div>
    <div ng-click="tabSelected = 1">Tab 2</div>
    <div ng-click="tabSelected = 2">Tab 3</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-show="tabSelected == 0">
        <h3>Some content 1 here</h3>
    </div><div ng-show="tabSelected == 1">
        <h3>Some content 2 here</h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tabSelected == 2">
        <h3>Some content 3 here</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-click="saveFactor()">Save and return to tab 1</button>
        <a ng-click="tabSelected = 0">Cancel and return to tab 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's my html.
I don't know why `tabSelected` updates view on cancel link with `ng-click="tabSelected = 0"` changing directly but not inside function `saveFactor()`. I know that function is called properly because of console log statement. And `tabSelected` changed as well but not the view. I can't `$scope.$apply()` inside that function because it's give me an error.

Comment: This is likely a scoping issue. I think some code is missing -- could you create a jsfiddle? Simple way to check would be to use an object instead (e.g. tabs.selected = 0, tabs.selected = 1, etc). That would persist through scopes.

Comment: You are right. I stripped my code just to show relevant parts. this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nogostradamus/fz4yx2zj/ works just fine. Have to find what's wrong in my version.

Comment: You can inspect your scope variables with [batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) in chrome. I think your scope could not find your variable. You can either use dot notation or setter function at the first controller that you create variable tabSelected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to use a function when modifying scope variables
HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
<div ng-click="changeTab(0)">Tab 1</div>
<div ng-click="changeTab(1)">Tab 2</div>
<div ng-click="changeTab(2)">Tab 3</div>
...
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="saveFactor()">Save and return to tab 1</button>
    <a ng-click="changeTab(0)">Cancel and return to tab 1</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.tabSelected = 0;

$scope.saveFactor = function () {
    console.log('here');
    $scope.tabSelected = 0;
    console.log($scope.tabSelected);
};
$scope.changeTab= function(tabNum){
    $scope.tabSelected = tabNum;
};
```

Comment: That works. So I have to stick with just functions and can't mix changing variable directly in the view and in the controller. Once I converted everything to function in controller it worked. Thanks